# Getting extra line using row seperator

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I'm using this regex to split one line into multiple group by 2 characters.

```
string.replaceAll("(.{2})", "$1\r\n")
```

Here is an example.

Like my input input string is like this

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

And output am getting like this

```
Output
->AB
->CD
->EF
->GH
->IJ
->
```

Is there any way so that I don't receive that last empty line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Manually remove the new line from the result
- Change your regex to: `(.{2})(?!$)`

Now the regex will catch all pairs except the last one, and you will not be replacing it with a new line.

Comment: Its not working string.replaceAll("(.{2})(?!$)") replaceAll(string, string) error because its having only one argument if I follow yours

Comment: @kelly `string.replaceAll("(.{2})(?!$)", "$1\r\n")`

Answer (score 1):

Other approach could be:

```
String.join(System.lineSeparator(), string.split("(?<=\\G..)"))
```

With `string.split("(?<=\\G..)")` you are splitting after every two characters, but since `split` by default removes trailing empty strings you will not get it in your result. So `"ABCD"` becomes `["AB", "CD"]` array.

Then using `String.join(delimiter, elements)` you can join elements from array into one string with specified delimiter between them, in our case OS line separator.

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/Idz0mN)

Comment: Hi @Pshemo..Can you please tell me one thing that...I'm reading file again like mentioned in above example after getting proper split with row separator "\n" as input file row seperator. And splitting file into multiple file using row separator "\r\n" for output file. But am receiving an extra line coming like I  was getting in my question. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify your problem more? I am not sure what you mean by "reading file again like mentioned in above example" since none of posted example includes reading file, but only processing text from String. I can only assume that by splitting file you mean adding line separators to string. Anyway without seeing [MCVE] I can only guess that you could use `println()` instead of `print()` which adds line separator after printed text. You may also forget about `\r` while handling only `\n` in `\r\n`. It i shard to say.